# El ultimo elemento de mi ListView se corta

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

**Finalmente solo añadi al listview la linea que pongo aqui  abajo y se solucionó, gracias por las respuestas!**

> android:paddingBottom="attr/actionBarSize"/>

Buenas el problema es que mi listview me muestra la lista, pero el ultimo elemento de la lista no lo muestra completo, si no que el ultimo se corta,:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver en la imagen Luis no aparewce por completo.

```
Lisview:`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/LvListaUsuarios"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>

Adaptador:`public class AdaptadorListaUsuarios extends ArrayAdapter<Usuario>{

    public AdaptadorListaUsuarios(Context context, ArrayList<Usuario> usuarios) {
        super(context, 0, usuarios);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lista_usuarios,parent,false);

        }

        TextView nombre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvUsuarioLista);

        TextView correo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCorreoLista);

        Usuario usuario = getItem(position);


    nombre.setText(usuario.getNombreUsuario());
    correo.setText(usuario.getEmail());
```

Comment: El que se vea o no, dependerá del tamaño de la pantalla. No creo que puedas controlar eso directamente desde el `ListView`

Comment: pudiste solucionarlo?
me pasa igual.Gracias

Comment: @Lucho solo añadi al listview 
 android:paddingBottom="attr/actionBarSize"/> y se solucionó, un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Cambia los valores de las propiedades de tu `ListView`  `android:layout_height` y `android:layout_weight` con valores `wrap_content`:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/LvListaUsuarios"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Puedes optar por usar `match_parent` pero en este caso aunque no se tengan suficientes elementos se mostrara tu `ListView` con toda la altura.

```
  <ListView
        android:id="@+id/LvListaUsuarios"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero sigue el mismo problema:S

Comment: @jlgf podrías agregar por favor la clase completa AdaptadorListaUsuarios  ?

Comment: Esta completa jeje, lo unico que le falta es al final el return convertView;

Answer (score 0):

Prueba añadiendo en tu ***XML*** un ***Space***, por ejemplo:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/LvListaUsuarios"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Space
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="50dp" />
```

Puedes modificar ***layout_height*** según tu necesidad.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pense en esa opcion pero variaria mucho el resultado dependiendo de la pantalla del movil

Comment: Está completo el XML en tu pregunta?  @jlgf

Comment: sí, sí, solo tengo el listview

Answer (score 0):

Respuesta simple y sencilla, si tu pantalla sólo muestra una lista entonces no te compliques y decláralo de la siguiente forma.

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LvListaUsuarios"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero sigue el mismo problema:S

Comment: haz probado en otros móviles tu aplicación ?

Comment: si amigo,  e igual :S